# How is 2nd and 3rd species in 4 part supposed to look like? How do I do it?

Tags: theory, species-counterpoint

[image]

[image]

If second species is the 1st pic (the one with half notes) and 3rd species is the 2nd pic, how do i do that in 4 part writing? Like both...combined? "2nd and 3rd species in 4 parts". Im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

In *Gradus ad Parnassum* the three- or four-part examples for 2nd through 4th species show one line performing the half-notes or the "active" part of the species, and the other voices all use whole notes, e.g. something like:

[image: counterpoint]

The "active" line could be moved to any part, or you could also try writing multiple voices with the active line, which is where florid counterpoint gets to, eventually. Or, you could alternate where the active part is, so maybe the tenor moves in quarter notes one measure, then switches to whole notes while some other voice moves in quarter notes. (Unless, of course, your instructor is looking for something specific, in which case you probably should do that.)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is a long and painful one...

Don't give up until you can do all of them at once.  For four parts, for example,  you'll have your CF in whole notes, one voice in half notes, one voice in quarters, and one in suspensions.  It's maddeningly difficult at first but if you persevere writing florid counterpoint in 4 parts will be a breeze.

Fux will do little to help you, though.  Check out Jeppesen's book on counterpoint instead.   You'll have to get good at movable clef though...